# fsockopen seems very slow

Tags: php, fsockopen

Why is this `fsockopen` so slow compared to the same request from a browser?

php fsockopen: `0.254` secs

browser: `0.070` secs

## fsockopen request

```
$time = microtime(true);

if($fp = fsockopen('ssl://domain.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 20)){
    echo "\n".(microtime(true) - $time);
    $this->request = 'POST '.$path.' HTTP/1.1'.$crlf
        .'Host: '.$this->host.$crlf
        .'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.$crlf
        .'Content-Length: '.$content_length.$crlf
        .'Connection: Close'.$crlf.$crlf
        .$body;
    fwrite($fp, $this->request);

    while($line = fgets($fp)){
        if($line !== false){
            $this->response .= $line;
        }
    }

    fclose($fp);
}

echo "\n".(microtime(true) - $time);
```

## fsockopen results

```
0.18865990638733
0.25424790382385
```

## request from browser

[image]

Comment: dns caching? reverse dns lookup time? there's more to a network call than just the time-in-flight on the wire.

Comment: how can I use DNS caching with fsockopen?

Comment: you don't. that's done at the system resolver level.

Comment: you mean in something like `/etc/hosts` or `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` ?

Comment: node. that just hardcodes dns mappings, and has nothing to do with the resolver.

Comment: How can I then speed up the request? TTL on the DNS is set to 59.. Even if I do quick multiple request after each other each request still takes the same time

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution here

[if connection is keep alive how to read until end of stream php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125463/if-connection-is-keep-alive-how-to-read-until-end-of-stream-php)

Answer (score 0):

It could be EOF problem, your fopen wait until timeout.

Try a lower timeout for faster return, but is not an elegant solution.

Other solution is to query connection manually with a bucle, like this example:

```
while (!feof($conn)) {
    print fgets($conn, 1024);
}
```

Source of example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1319434/3518053

Comment: I'm performing tests but I can't reproduce the problem, with some example pages the fopen connection is very fast.  May be you could give me an url which can reproduce problem?